# How to use usecontext using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to use usecontext within the childcomponents of component that is wrapped with context provider.

i want to set the loading state within the useAnother hook of parent comopnent and then have the loading state accessible to all child components.

below is my code,

```
export function useLoad() {
    const { refetch: refetchItems } = useGetItems();
    const { refetch: refetchOwnedItems } = useListOwnedItems();
    return async function() {
        await refreshCompany();
        refetchItems();
        refetchOwnedItems();
    };  
}

function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }
    }
} 

export const LoadingContext = React.createContext(true); 

function Main ({user}: Props) {
    const isLoading = useAnother(user.id); //fetching isLoading here from useHook
    return (
        <LoadingContext.Provider value={isLoading}> //also here error type                      void is not assignable to type boolean
            <Wrapper>
                <React.suspense>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route 
                            path="/" 
                            render={routeProps => (
                                <FirstComp {...routeProps} />
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route 
                            path="/items" 
                            render={routeProps => (
                                <SecondComp {...routeProps} />
                            )}
                        />
                        //many other routes like these
                    </Switch>
                </React.suspense>
            </Wrapper>
        </LoadingContext.Provider>
    );
}

function FirstComponent () {
    const isLoading = React.useContext(LoadingContext); //this throws error
}
```

accessing isLoading within FirstComponent throws error

**argument of type ({user}: props) => Element or null is not assignab**le to parameter of type 'context'**

also get error for value prop where i use LoadingContext.Provider "type void is not assignable to type boolean"

could someone help me fix this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useAnother(user.id);` doesn't return `boolean` as required from `createContext(true);`

```js
function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }
    }

    return isLoading
}
```